# richfaces 4 rich:tabPanel switchType="client" exception

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I want to use the richfaces 4 rich:tabPanel and I have this code:

```
<rich:tabPanel id="tabMenu" switchType="client">
                <rich:tab id="overview" header="Overview">
                </rich:tab>
                <rich:tab id="results" header="Results">
                </rich:tab>
            </rich:tabPanel>
```

when I try to acces the page with the tabMenu I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert client of type class java.lang.String to class org.richfaces.component.SwitchType
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:329)
```

The code works fine if I remove switchType attribute

I suspect that it might be a dependency problem, and these are the dependencies I have:

```
richfaces-components-ui 4.1.0 Final
richfaces-core-impl 4.1.0 Final
```

Any idea why I get this exception

Comment: Must be something you're doing wrong. Make sure you don't have spaces anywhere around that string parameter or anything else that will result in something other than pure `client` being parsed. Also try other switchTypes `server` or `ajax`

Comment: it seems that I had an old dependency of el-impl. (btw... who is holding you prisoner here? :) )